# Conditionally enable keys as standard function keys

Tags: macos, keybindings

On a Macbook Pro, by default, the topmost row can either act as std function keys (so you don't have to press fn) or utility/media keys (brightness, volume etc) and then you can toggle the default behavior of keys using a system preference as show in image below.

[image: System Pref]

When I am coding (i.e. using apps like IntelliJ, VSCode, Sublime), I prefer those keys to behave like std function keys (F1...F12) i.e. without needing the press fn every time.

But when I am browsing or watching videos, I want the volume and brightness keys to work without having to press the fn key.

Is there any app/script that can toggle this setting based on which Application I am using?